# Push source to scratch org fails but mdapi:deploy works

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, mdapi, source

I am in the process of converting an existing Managed Package to Salesforce DX and

1. Retrieved the Metadata from the packaging org
2. Converted it to Source format
3. Created a scratch org and
4. pushed source to scratch org

The last step fails with hundreds of errors which all come from it not finding a Custom Field on a packaged Custom Object.

> No such column 'customField__c' on entity
>   'NAMESPACE__CustomObject__c'.

The Metadata is there and I checked ALL the errors and nothing else is there.

I am also successful to do a `mdapi:deploy` to the same scratch org. It works without andy problems. But the problem persists. When I pull from the org and push it into another scratch I again see the same error.

Comment: Weird. You have `"namespace": "NAMESPACE"` in your project-scratch-def.json?

Comment: Yes I do and linked it from my DevHUb.

Comment: So a bug (e.g. missing feature) in `source:push`? Think you are stuck with e.g. stripping out everything but the data model and then adding pieces back in until you find the problem area which you might or might not be able to workaround. There is also a small chance that there is useful information in the `.sfdx/sfdx.log` file.

Comment: But the object metadata also references VF pages and then everything goes in circles....

Comment: Silly question, but have you looked through every single error in the output from sfdx? If I do something sfdx doesn't like in field X__c (which has many references), I get one error about X__c and then lots of errors about X__c not existing in references. Could there be a significant error hiding in all the rest of them?

Comment: I'd forgotten those circular references. Horrible. Hacking to figure out the problem area would probably be needed for a Salesforce case to go anywhere in any case. Fingers crossed someone posts better ideas here instead though.

Comment: @Aidan good hint. I selectivly deployed the objects and got as first error Cannot specify a gender for a gender neutral language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a field named `namedCredential__c` in my Custom Object metadata. This made the deployment fail with

> No such column 'namedCredential__c' on entity 'NS__CustomObject__c'.
>   If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the
>   '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the
>   describe call for the appropriate names. (63:34)

In my .forceignore I had

```
package.xml
**appMenu
**appSwitcher
**profiles
**settings
**emailservices
**namedCredential
**connectedApp
*crt
```

and I guess `**namedCredential` just ignored my field why syncing.